# the cmdlet cannot run because the -ContentType parameter is not a valid Content-Type header

Tags: powershell

Hi I have below Powershell cmdlet running in my devops pipeline which is uploading an artifact in a sharePoint library. Till now things were working fine but I am getting below error for one of the project. Not sure how can I fix this. If any one knows anything here.

My Powershell code>

```
    $fileSize = (Get-Item -LiteralPath $file).length
    write-host "*******"
    write-host $file
    write-host $fileSize
    write-host "*******"
    $uploadURLObject = GET-UPLOADLINK -clientId $clientId -clientSecret $clientSecret -nameofFile $nameWithoutExtension
    $tokenObject = GET-TOKEN -clientId $clientId -clientSecret $clientSecret
    $uploadHeaders = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $uploadHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/zip")
    $uploadHeaders.Add("Content-Range", "bytes " + 0 +"-" + ($fileSize-1) + "/" + $fileSize)
    $uploadHeaders.Add("Content-Length", $fileSize)
    $uploadHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+ $tokenObject.access_token)    
   # $uploadBody = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file)    
    $uploadBody = Get-Content -LiteralPath $file
    write-host $uploadBody
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod $uploadURLObject.uploadUrl -Method 'PUT' -Headers $uploadHeaders -Body $uploadBody
   # $response = Invoke-RestMethod $uploadURLObject.uploadUrl -Method 'PUT' -Headers $uploadHeaders -Infile $file -SkipHeaderValidation 
    $response | ConvertTo-Json
```

Error Message

> Invoke-RestMethod : The cmdlet cannot run because the -ContentType
> parameter is not a valid Content-Type header. Specify a valid
> Content-Type for -ContentType, then retry. To suppress header
> validation, supply the -SkipHeaderValidation parameter.

Update: I checked my Headers key and value and nothing seems unusual.

```
Key: Content-Type    Value: application/zip
Key: Content-Range    Value: bytes 0-66704/66705
Key: Content-Length    Value: 66705
Key: Authorization    Value: Bearer rzoQ6Ls7YoaQGls8MBlPVScBPA...dfd
```

Comment: Did you try supplying `-SkipHeaderValidation`?

Comment: yes i get "Bad Request
Bad Request - Invalid Content Length
HTTP Error 400. There is an invalid content length or chunk length in the request.
At D:\a\1\s\.......\ReleaseNotewithUpload.ps1:88 char:17
+ … $response = Invoke-RestMethod $uploadURLObject.uploadUrl -Method 'PUT …
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
"  as error

Comment: Can you try to remove the `Content-Type` key from the dictionary and just pass it as a parameter using `-ContentType "application/zip"`?

Comment: What do you mean passing as parameter? where in above code?

Comment: Remove the Content-Type from `$uploadHeaders` and pass it as a parameter of `Invoke-RestMethod` as follows: `Invoke-RestMethod $uploadURLObject.uploadUrl -Method 'PUT' -Headers $uploadHeaders -Body $uploadBody -ContentType "application/zip"`

Comment: Error: there is no parameter as ContentType. Check the spelling.

Comment: One thing I figured out if I completely remove the Content-Type line it works. But I dont know how it will impact my code in future

Comment: Sorry not Content-Type but its Content-Length which I removed and it worked. I kept Content-Type as it is in my code above, But I commented out my Content-Length. anyone can explain Why this happened?

Comment: Can you try incremeting the range from `0-66704` to `0-66705`?

Comment: still the same error

Answer (score 1):

Despite Content-Length sometimes being a required parameter, try to remove this: $uploadHeaders.Add("Content-Length", $fileSize)

The reason behind this based on my experience I believe is that Powershell automatically calculates the Content Length for you, and automatically adds it to the headers, based on your passed body and whenever the method is PUT.

In other words, if you specified it manually, it will turn out to be a duplicate and that misleading error will be generated.